# How to list all variables listed in a dot env file (e.g: .env.local.example)

Tags: node.js, yaml, dotenv

I'd like to iterate over a list (in Node.js) of env variables defined in a `.env.local.example`, **without loading those variables.** *(they must not replace the existing variables)*

So, I basically want to read those, should I use a dot-env specific tool, or can I simply grab any YAML parser?

I don't care about the values, I only care about the keys in the `.env.local.example` file.

So, given the following .env.local.example:

```
FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET_KEY=
MAGIC_AUTH_SECRET_KEY=
```

I want to get an array of strings `['FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET_KEY', 'MAGIC_AUTH_SECRET_KEY']`.

Comment: Please state a reason for downvoting.

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question.

Comment: I don't know much about dotenv, but what I know is that this format is not [YAML](https://yaml.org). The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) never mention the word "YAML".

Comment: Why not just load the variables and do something like this: let env_arr = Object.keys(process.env)?

Comment: @Vadorequest I've updated my answer, using that solution will avoid replacing the existing env variables.

Comment: @tinita Thanks for pointing this out, I had mistakenly assumed it was YAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to load your `.env.local.example` to avoid replacing of existing variables.

Try to use `fs`, with the help of regex.

Here's an example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let arr_env = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.env.local.example'), 'utf-8').match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+/gm);
console.log(arr_env);

// Expected Result: ['FAUNADB_SERVER_SECRET_KEY', 'MAGIC_AUTH_SECRET_KEY']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Console.log(Object.keys(process.env))
```

But just be cautious, local system adds extra variables too (like vsCode add some different things too, that got added in process.env also), so you might get extra variables from you system too.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't do what I want. There will be tons of noise indeed, it's unpredictable. :)